# How do I get my pre-populated Default.realm file onto a device?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a realm file that is already populated with data that needs to be there when the app is loaded on a device.

What can I do to get the realm file onto my device for testing and what do I need to do to make sure it is already there when someone downloads the app from the app store?

I am using Swift.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add your database file to the Xcode project, i.e. "preloaded.realm"
Make sure you select the add to targets, when first dropping in your file
[image: Add to targets]

Then (taking from the migration example) you can do something like this to copy that preloaded file to your default directory. This will create a read/write realm

```
// copy over old data files for migration
let defaultPath = RLMRealm.defaultRealmPath()
let defaultParentPath = defaultPath.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent

let v0Path = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("preloaded.realm")
NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(defaultPath, error: nil)
NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(v0Path, toPath: defaultPath, error: nil)
```

Here is a link to that general code https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift-2.2/Migration/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: Should I do this while running the virtual iOS device or run it with my real device connected?

Comment: Also, does it matter where I copy the file in my project? Does it need to be in the same folder as AppDelegate.swift or some other location?

Comment: Either one works, if you need to read/write it needs to be in documents directory.

Yes, intially you need to put it in the same place as your AppDelegate.swift, but when you copy it you can put it elsewhere

Comment: I am not sure why, but this isn't working for me. I have the populated default.realm file in the same folder with the rest of my code. When I run the app it still has an empty realm. Note that I copied your code and pasted it into the appdelegate.swift file inside the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions block but outside of the migration block. I also changed "preloaded.realm" to "default.realm". Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you select the add to target, when first dropping in your file https://www.dropbox.com/s/hwnzyiivqjvtujm/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-18%20at%2010.33.39%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: updated link to migration example: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift-2.2/Migration/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: Thanks Adam! Added that to the original

Answer (score 3):

You'll first have to create the realm file you want to ship with your app. Once you have that, add it to your app's Xcode project and copy it into the bundle (which Xcode should do automatically).

At this point, the app should be able to access the bundled file (you can use [NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(_:ofType:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:) to get the path).

You can either create a read-only realm at this path (see [RLMRealm(path:readOnly:error:)](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.88.0/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#//api/name/realmWithPath:readOnly:error:)), or copy it to your Documents directory to create a read-write realm file.

You should refer to our [migration example](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples#migration-1) for more details on how to do this.

Comment: I am using swift and I find it very difficult to translate the objective-c api documentation. Can you be more specific on how I can accomplish my task? (Sorry I didn't specify earlier that I am using swift.)

Comment: My answer is using Swift methods and initializers, since I know that's what you're using from several other questions of yours. yoshyosh's answer is correct as well, and has inline sample code which should be plenty to get you going.