# Create a new Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I've used Realm.io a long time ago, back then you'd create or fetch an existing realm by passing a String as key (could be with or without.realm).

Now I'm building an app with realm.io in swift. However I can't seem to figure out how to create a new realm.
In the docs I saw you could get a realm by passing a Realm.COnfiguration object which has a fileUrl and readonly proprty (true or false).

Anyways, Do I just touch an empty file? or how can I create a new Realm?

This is what I have, named is a string which must be dynamic in my case:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
    fileURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(named, withExtension: "realm"),
    readOnly: true
)

return try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well now the way I tried to construct the URL doesn't work since it generates nil. I however need an URL which will be used.

A simple construction like this will do.

```
let url = NSURL(string: (NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL?.absoluteString)! +  named + ".realm")
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to create new Realm or open an existing one for readonly access?

If you want to create new Realm you can just use a default Realm like this:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
```

You can also specify a custom path where Realm should be created, see more in [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realms).

Also note that Realm produces extra files when you open it, so it's not a good idea to open it inside the app's bundle directory. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534123/how-do-i-get-my-pre-populated-default-realm-file-onto-a-device) if you want to have pre-populated Realm on your device.

Comment: Hi, as I said the name of the realm it will be dynamic, iin this case it should be so dynamic that you can't know up front which will be available. Lets say like popping up a new service somewhere in the cloud, this app should be able to talk to it.

Therefore I want a db to be created on the fly, like my own answer resolves this.

Good call on the directories, but for my current situation it is fine since it's no way ever going to be a production application, more like a demo and learning thingy for me.

Thanks though

Comment: I see, so `Realm(fileURL:)` should work for you in this case, just make sure you specify correct URL (and you have a waiting permission for this URL).

Comment: It works right now so I assume it's set up correctly ;-). I will only need to run this in dev mode anyway